# Problems allowing custom UserControl to be dragged between panels

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, drag-and-drop, panel

In my program, I have a bank of custom UserControls all nested inside of a scrollable panel.  Currently, I have [this code](https://gist.github.com/JPeroutek/9c40f8f05dd89246ca1d) to allow me to drag and move controls *within* their current panel.  What I'd like is to be able to drag them into another panel (within the same form), so that the user can create a visual organization of the Controls.  The plan is then to store their positions (relative to the panel) and use that to create a schedule.

My issue is that whenever I begin dragging the controls, the panel they are in just gets resized and the controls never move to the other panel.

I have tried setting `AllowDrop` to `True` in the destination panel, and I've tried resetting the parent of the control you are currently dragging to the new panel.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To move between containers you'll need to add code to your class that will move the control between containers when the boundary of the original container is reached.  Also, in my brief attempt to review this, I had all sorts of issues with your supplied code.  I can tell you why your panel is being resized, because your code tells it to with the Container.Left and Container.Top value changes.  It's almost like you're not allowing the control to be moved, just moving it's parent around on the form, simulating movement of the control.

Comment: Indeed...you're only "simulating" drag and drop with that code.  You should implement **actual** drag and drop code using the built-in .Net drag/drop functionality.  If you need it to look like the control itself is being dragged, you can create a dynamic icon from the UserControl itself when the drag is initiated.  Do some research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more digging on this and what you want is very doable, but will take some heavy lifting on your part.  I'm including a brief sample here, to get you started.  Keep in mind that this doesn't account for parent containers when handling drag/drop of controls, so you'll need to add that, as well as edge detection for re-parenting while in a drag.

Form1.vb:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Dim _dragging As Boolean
    Dim _startX As Integer
    Dim _startY As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        For Each ctl As Control In Controls
            AddHandler ctl.MouseDown, AddressOf StartDrag
            AddHandler ctl.MouseMove, AddressOf WhileDragging
            AddHandler ctl.MouseUp, AddressOf EndDrag
        Next
        For Each ctl As Control In Controls
            For Each item In My.Settings.controlLocations
                If Split(item, "!")(0) = ctl.Name Then
                    ctl.Location = New Point(Split(item, "!")(1), Split(item, "!")(2))
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartDrag(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        _dragging = True
        _startX = e.X
        _startY = e.Y
    End Sub

    Private Sub WhileDragging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        If _dragging = True Then
            sender.Location = New Point(sender.Location.X + e.X - _startX, sender.Location.Y + e.Y - _startY)
            Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub EndDrag(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        _dragging = False
        My.Settings.controlLocations.Clear()
        For Each ctl As Control In Controls
            My.Settings.controlLocations.Add(ctl.Name & "!" & ctl.Location.X & "!" & ctl.Location.Y)
        Next
        My.Settings.Save()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I appreciate the help